# AutoCompleteTextView listeners

Tags: android

I'm creating input with drown menu, which fetches data from server with input from user and adds the data to the list.

I got this code:

```
from_autocompl = (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.from_autocompl);
        from_autocompl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    new JSONParse().execute();
                    if (ImDoneWithJSON == 1)
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<List_From_JSON> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List_From_JSON>(
                                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                        from_autocompl.setAdapter(adapter);
                        ImDoneWithJSON = 0;
                    }

            }
        });
```

Now the problem I got is:
 I need to know which items in dropdown list is clicked.

Usually it is done by using `onItemClick`, but I already have `TextWatch` listener added to `from_autocompl` and android allows by default only one listener and now I want to know how to do it. How to by pass this?

Answer (score 2):

You no need to use textChange Listener Use this, AutoComplete Box have the default property of textwatcher

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// private AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
 private MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoComplete;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the defined string-array 
    String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorList);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,colors);

    //autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    multiAutoComplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoComplete);

    // set adapter for the auto complete fields
//  autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    multiAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    // specify the minimum type of characters before drop-down list is shown
    //autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
    multiAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);
    // comma to separate the different colors
    multiAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    // when the user clicks an item of the drop-down list
    multiAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MultiAutoComplete: " +
                        "you add color "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```